# Как конвертировать int в float64?

Tags: golang

Не получается конвертировать `int` в `float`. Пробовал во так:

```golang
float(integer_value)
```

Но данный способ не работает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Типа `float` нет в го. Есть только `float32` и `float64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `float64` или `float32`.

### Пример ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9IM-pRinyEA)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 5
    f := float64(i)
    fmt.Printf("f = %f\n", f)
}
```

У `float32` точность один знак после запятой.